# Pipeline Development with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, windows, c#-4.0, plugins, add-on

Microsoft offers Pipeline Development via its Extensibility framework where the application can consume External Addins. I have successfully developed an extensible application on a Windows Console Project.

Now I need to implement an extensible website which accepts Addins, I googled for days for guidelines to do so, unfortunately I couldn't find any resources.

So, my question: is it possible to do that ? if yes can you provide any resources to learn from ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can't use M.A.F with Asp.Net because the Grabdge Collection will be very ugly.

Instead if someone ever will counterpart this question, The answer is:

You will need to use **M.E.F (Managed Extensibility Framework)** which comes as part of **.Net 4.0+**